# When searching Active Directory account, System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The time limit for this request was exceeded

Tags: directory

I am getting error when i search for LDAP users in AD. If I restrict the DirectorySearcher.SizeLimit = 1, then i am getting the result (1 result returned). But when I increase the SizeLimit to more than 1 (SizeLimit = 2 also), I am getting "**the time limit for this request was exceeded**" error. Please let me know how can I debug this error and what are the possible scenarios because of which I get this error.

Also note that the error comes only when my DirectorySearcher.Filter has ID, Name, Email. If I am searching only by Name or ID or Email individually, I am not getting any timeout error and I am getting results.

**Filter for search "a" with ID, Name & Email (This throws timeout error):**

```
(|
  (&(|(objectClass=person)(objectCategory=user))(!objectCategory=computer)((|(samAccountname=a*)(givenname=a*)(mail=a*))))
  (&(|(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(objectClass=groupOfNames))(!objectCategory=computer)(cn=a*))
)
```

**Filter for search "a" with ID (This works well)**:

```
(|
  (&(|(objectClass=person)(objectCategory=user))(!objectCategory=computer)(samAccountname=a*))
  (&(|(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(objectClass=groupOfNames))(!objectCategory=computer)(cn=a*))
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query is not well formed and has some redundant and incorrect information.

I would specify objectCategory=person.  And if you do that, you don't need objectClass=user, as it is included in the objectCategory=person.

You may want to try this:

```
(|
  (&(objectCategory=person)(|(samAccountname=a*)(givenname=a*)(mail=a*)))
  (&(|(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(objectClass=groupOfNames))(cn=a*))
)
```

Also note:

"...if you have a choice between using objectCategory and objectClass, it is recommended that you use objectCategory. That is because objectCategory is both single valued and indexed, while objectClass is multi-valued and not indexed (except on Windows Server 2008 and above). A query using a filter with objectCategory will be more efficient than a similar filter with objectClass. Windows Server 2008 domain controllers (and above) have a special behavior that indexes the objectClass attribute. You can take advantage of this if all of your domain controllers are Windows Server 2008, or if you specify a Windows Server 2008 domain controller in your query. "

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The filter you mentioned is working well. But I wanted to know which was causing the error. You removed **!objectCategory=computer** and **objectClass=person** and added **objectCategory=person** instead of **objectCategory=user** from the original filter. Can you please explain why these 2 were remove.

Comment: If the query is for objectCategory=person, that already includes objectClass=person, and will not return computers, so the !objectCategory=person and !objectCategory=computer are not required.